# Commutativity of finite sum

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory

I want to prove that changing the order of the elements of a finite sum, or in more general, of a comutative (and associative?) operation has the same result. I believe it can be done by induction, but I don't know how to represent the "order" of n elements.

For example if there are 2 elements $a_1$ and $a_2$, how do I prove that the only ways to organize them in a sum are $a_1+a_2$ and $a_2+a_1$? It seems extremely "obvious", but I have no idea how to prove that, let alone for the case with n elements.

Comment: How many ways are there to list $n$ elements in order? Well there are $n$ choices for the first one, then $n-1$ choices for the second one, then $n-2$ choices for the third one...

Comment: Yes, but that I think begs the question. How do you prove that there are $n!$ ways to list $n$ elements in order? How do you prove that it applies in the context of a finite sum?

Comment: I don't see what finite sums have to do with this... One proves (by induction, say) that on a set of cardinality $n$ there are $n!$ different linear orders